# find the k-th smallest in three or N number of sorted arrays in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, median, divide-and-conquer

Is there a way to find the kth smallest in 0(log n) time in 3 or more sorted arrays like we do in 2  and 1 sorted arrays

Comment: kth smallest from all the numbers in all the arrays?

Comment: You can't do it in O(log(n)) time because you need to look at every array so it has to be at least O(n) and according to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/20955 there is an optimal solution.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Yes. The whole diea is to do this like we do it when we try to find the kth smallest in 2 arrays. I just cant see how to modify that for 3 arrays